# Convert data.frames within a list into numeric vectors

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have got 10 data.frames, each one with only one column, contained within a list and I have to convert them into numeric vectors.

Here an example of my 10th data.frame within the list:

```
[[10]]
             x
1   115.065808
2    97.358465
3    92.434613
4   146.454943
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want it to be? data.frames typically have a name in the column, even if it is generic (like v1) Would you rather these data.frames were vectors?

Comment: From https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html: "The column names should be non-empty, and attempts to use empty names will have unsupported results.".

Comment: Do you basically want to cast them to vectors? Try `as.numeric`, https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/numeric.html

Comment: Hi Imo, yes vectors!

Comment: `your_new_list <- lapply(your_list, as.numeric)` should do the job.

Comment: @m-dz I get an error with `as.numeric`. I'd suggest `your_new_list <- lapply(your_list, unlist, use.names = FALSE)`.

Comment: @Imo, thanks! please post your answer I will celebrate you :)

Comment: @lmo, yeah, this was just an initial thought, not tested. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to convert a list of data.frames, each with one column to a list of unnamed vectors.

1) Using `unlist`

```
your_new_list <- lapply(your_list, unlist, use.names = FALSE)
```

2) Using the extraction operator, `[[`

```
your_new_list <- lapply(your_list, "[[", 1)
```

Here's a sample list to try it out:

```
set.seed(1234)
your_list <- list(data.frame(a=1:10), data.frame(a=rnorm(50)), data.frame(b=letters[1:10]))
```

Comment: great! very exhaustive answer :)